# Subdomain not working with https

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

Issued wildcard SSL but still unable to use https with subdomain.

Main domain is working fine with the http and https both but the subdomain works only with http

> and https://{subdomain}.{domain}.com **generates 404 error**

.htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Turn on HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.domain.com?/$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

- Using Apache in linux.
- Main domain is in PHP Wordpress.
- Subdomain is in PHP Codeigniter MVC.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you purchased SSL for subdomain?

Comment: and do you using subdomain wildcards for your main domain ?

Comment: I think you need to generate the certificate for main and subdomain, wildcard will not work. (Atleast in let's encrypt you have to mention all the domain and subdomains).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Turn on HTTPS
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.domain.com?/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

Your "force HTTPS" directives are invalid. This looks like it might result in a 404 (otherwise, it would result in a redirect-loop). The above directive redirects the request to the query string, clearing the URL-path. The `?` looks misplaced. (Incidentally, this is similar to what you are doing in the rewrite below - but this is very different.)

Just try removing those directives altogether for now. Do you still get a 404?

The above should be written something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

(Change the `R` to `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK.)

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
> :
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

*Aside:* These rewrites are also inconsistent. The first one internally rewrites using *path information*. The second one rewrites to the query string. You should be doing one or the other, not both (unless this is a mash of two different systems)?